# Using regex to extract a matching pattern from a string and assign it to a variable using perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, scripting

I am seeking advice on extracting a section of a string, that is always occurs as the first instance data between parenthesis using perl and regex and assign that value to a variable.

Here is the precise situation, I am using perl and regex to extract the courseID from a university catalog and assign it to a variable.  Please consider the following:

- BIO-2109-01 (12345) Introduction to Biology
- CHM-3501-F2-01 (54321) Introduction to Chemistry
- IDS-3250-01 (98765) History of US (1860-2000)
- SPN-1234-02-F1 (45678) Spanish History (1900-2010)

The typical format is [course-section-name] [(courseID)] [courseName]

My goal is to create a script which can take each entry, one at a time, assign it to a variable and then use regex to extract only the courseID and assign only the courseID to a variable.

My approach has been to use search and replace to replace everything not matching that with '' and then saving what is left (the courseID) to the variable.  Here are a few examples of what I have tried the following:

```
$string = "BIO-2109-01 (12345) Introduction to Biology";
($courseID = $string) =~ s/[^\d\d\d\d\d]//g;
print $courseID;
```

Result: 21090112345 --- printing the course-section-name and courseID

```
$string = "BIO-2109-01 (12345) Introduction to Biology";
$($courseID = $string) =~ s/[^\b\(\d{5}\)]\b//g;
print $courseID;
```

Result:  210901(12345) --- printing course-section-name, parens, and courseID

So I haven't had much luck with search and replace - however I found this nugget:

```
\(([^\)]+)\)
```

On http://regexr.com/ that will match the parens section.  However, it would also match multiple parans, including for example (abc).

I'm not really sure at this point how to do something like this:

```
$string = "BIO-2109-01 (12345) Introduction to Biology";
($courseID = $string) =~ [magicRegex_goes_here];
print courseID;
```

result 12345

OR, better:

```
$string = IDS-3250-01 (98765) History of US (1860-2000)
($courseID = $string) =~ [magicRegex_goes_here];
print courseID;
```

result 98765

Any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated.  I have tried everything I know and can research in regards to regex to solve this problem.  If there is anymore information I can include please ask away.

**UPDATE**

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $file = './data/enrollment.csv';      #File this script generates
my $course = "";                         #Complete course string [name-of-course] [(courseID)] [course_name]
my @arrayCourses = "";                   #Array of courseIDs
my $i = "";                              #i in for loop
my $courseID = "";                       #Extracted course ID
my $userName = "";                       #Username of person we are enrolling
my $action = "add,";                     #What we are doing to user
my $permission = "teacher,";             #What permissions to assign to user
my $stringToPrint = "";                  #Concatinated string to write to file
my $n = "\n";                            #\n
my $c = ",";                             #,

#BEGIN PROGRAM

print "Enter the username \n";

chomp($userName = <STDIN>);               #Get the enrollee username from user

print "\n";

print "Enter course name and press enter.  Enter 'x' to end. \n";  #prompt for course names

while ($course ne 'x') {
        chomp($course = <STDIN>);
        if ($course ne "x") {
                if (($courseID) = ($course =~ /[^(]+\(([^)]+)\)/) ) {     #nasty regex to extract courseID - thnx PerlDuck and zdim
                        push @arrayCourses, $courseID;                    #put the courseID into array
                }
                else {
                        print "Cannot process last entry check it";
                }
        }
        else {
                last;
        }
}

shift @arrayCourses;                      #Remove first entry from array - add,teacher,,username

open(my $fh,'>', $file);                  #open file

for $i (@arrayCourses)                    #write array to file
{
        $stringToPrint= join "", $action, $permission, $i, $c, $userName, $n ;
        print $fh $stringToPrint;
}

close $fh;
```

That'll do it!  Suggestions or improvements are always welcome!  Thanks @PerlDuck and @zdim

Comment: +1 for showing your attempts! Note that `[…]` denotes a _character class_ which basically means _one (arbitrary) character of the characters between `[` and `]`_. So `[ab\dL]` matches _one of_ `a`, `b`, a digit, or `L` and not all of them in a row.

Answer (score 2):

Since you nailed down the format

```
my ($section, $id, $name) = 
    $string =~ /^\s* ([^(]+) \(\s* ([^)]+) \)\s* (.+) $/x;
```

The key here is the *negated character class*, `[^...]`, which matches any one character other than those listed inside following the `^` (which makes it "negated"). The un-escaped parenthesis *capture* the match, except inside a character class `[]` where they are taken as literal.

It first matches all consecutive characters other than `(`, so up to first `(`, what is captured by the pair of `( )` around it. Then all other than `)`, so up to the first closing paren, also captured by its own pair `( )`. This comes between literal parenthesis `\( ... \)`, which are outside of `( )` since we don't want them captured. Then all the rest is captured, `(.+)`, requiring at least some characters since `+` means *one* or more. Note though that these can be spaces. We exclude possible leading white space from the first capture, by matching it specifically before the capturing parenthesis, and extract (some of) possible spaces around id-parenthesis.

The `/x` modifier allows use of spaces (and comments and newlines) inside, what helps reaadbility. The match operator returns a list of all matches, which we assign to variables. Note, even if there is only one match it still returns (it as) a list. See [Regular Expressions Tutorial (perlretut)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

Then, assuming that you have the catalog in a file

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $file = 'catalog.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

while (my $line = <$fh>) 
{
    next if $line =~ /^\s*$/;  # skip empty lines

    # Strip leading and trailing white space
    $line =~ s{^\s*|\s*$}{}g;

    my ($section, $id, $name) = 
        $line =~ /^ ([^(]+) \(\s* ([^)]+) \)\s* (.+) $/x
            or do {
                warn "Error with expected format -- ";
                next;
            };

    say "$section, $id, $name";
}
close $fh;
```

I use `s{}{}` delimiters since `s///` confuse markup's syntax highlighter with this pattern, which is also a good demonstration since these sometimes help readability a lot.

You would store the retrieved variables in a suitable data structure. Any combination of arrays and hashes (and their references) comes to mind, depending on what need be done with them later.  See [Cookbook of Data Structures (perldsc)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

Note on the error handling.  Since none of the matches involve `*` (allowing *zero* matches -- nothing), if any component of your format isn't as expected there won't be a match at all and we get an error.  The `.+` is extremely permissive but it still requires *something* to be there. This is why the trailing space is first stripped, so that the last pattern `(.+)` cannot be satisfied by spaces alone.

If the only objective *is* the course id and we are *certain* that the first parenthesis are around it

```
my ($id) = $line =~ / \(\s* ([^)]+) \) /x  or do { ... };
```

We now only need to match and capture the middle piece, something inside parenthesis.

Comment: @ikegami  Yes, thank you -- was just editing, to clean up and add error checking and such.  Thank you for the edit.

Comment: Thank you!  I stole the idea for file handling and opening a file from your post.  In my code I write to the file, but I had no idea how to open a file in perl.  Also, I haven't sat down to fully go through your regex, yet.  I needed to get this script up, but I plan on going through.  Regex is something I really want to be solid at.  Thank you for your response @zdim

Comment: @squadguy Great, I'm glad that it's useful beyond the regex.  This is indeed a basic way to handle a file, which will cover most needs.  But you want to work through basics.One set of sources is Perl's documentation, and as for files it's firstly [perlopentut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html). The other is your favorite book.  The same goes for regex. Work through basics carefully and you'll immediately have a very useful tool.  After the basics it's _much_ easier to keep picking up.

Comment: @squadguy  I added to the regex explanation a little bit, it may be worth re-reading.

Comment: @ikegami Thank you for further comments!  I was hoping to make it clear, while I am hesitatant to post something here which may allow suspect data to pass. I'd rather err on the other side.  However, you are right, there are other ways. It did require a bit more, and some editing around.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    if (my ($courseID) = ($line =~ /[^(]+\(([^)]+)\)/) ) {
        print "course-ID = $courseID; -- line was $line";
    }
}

__DATA__
BIO-2109-01 (12345) Introduction to Biology
CHM-3501-F2-01 (54321) Introduction to Chemistry
IDS-3250-01 (98765) History of US (1860-2000)
SPN-1234-02-F1 (45678) Spanish History (1900-2010)
```

**Output:**

```
course-ID = 12345; -- line was BIO-2109-01 (12345) Introduction to Biology
course-ID = 54321; -- line was CHM-3501-F2-01 (54321) Introduction to Chemistry
course-ID = 98765; -- line was IDS-3250-01 (98765) History of US (1860-2000)
course-ID = 45678; -- line was SPN-1234-02-F1 (45678) Spanish History (1900-2010)
```

The pattern I used, `/[^(]+\(([^)]+)\)/`, can also be written as

```
/ [^(]+     # 1 or more characters that are not a '('
  \(        # a literal '('. You must escape that because you don't want
            # to start it a capture group.
  ([^)]+)   # 1 or more chars that are not a ')'.
            # The sorrounding '(' and ')' capture this match
  \)        # a literal ')'
/x
```

The `/x` modifier allows you to insert spaces, comments, and even newlines right in the pattern.

---

Just in case you're unsure about the `/x`. You can indeed write:

```
while( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    if (my ($courseID) = ($line =~ / [^(]+   # …
                                     \(      # …
                                     ([^)]+) # …
                                     \)      # …
                                    /x ) ) {
        print "course-ID = $courseID; -- line was $line";
    }
}
```

That's probably **not nice to read** but you can also store the regex in a **separate variable**:

```
my $pattern = 
    qr/ [^(]+     # 1 or more characters that are not a '('
        \(        # a literal '(' (you must escape it)
        ([^)]+)   # 1 or more chars that are not a ')'.
                  # The sorrounding '(' and ')' capture this match
        \)        # a literal ')'
      /x;
```

And then:

```
if (my ($courseID) = ($line =~ $pattern)) {
    …
}
```

Comment: I stole parts of you while loop and the regex you provided and included them in my code.  I still haven't really sat down to digest your regex yet, but it's on my shortlist.  I plan on learning perl for its text processing power.

I really appreciate your response - I wouldn't have been able to construct that regex.